# Error parsing JSON data from Facebook using FQL

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to parse a result (JSON) fetched from the Facebook API using FQL in an Android Application.

I have been able to parse all of the result set except this part:

```
[10151392619250579,10151392618640579,10151392618590579,10151392618785579,10151392618835579,10151392618885579,10151392619010579,10151392619155579]
```

The FQL query I am making is:

```
SELECT app_data FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0 LIMIT 200
```

Which returns a result like this:

```
{
    "app_data": {
        "attachment_data": "[]",
        "images": "[10151392619250579,10151392618640579,10151392618590579,10151392618785579,10151392618835579,10151392618885579,10151392619010579,10151392619155579]",
        "photo_ids": [
          "10151392619250579",
          "10151392618640579",
          "10151392618590579",
          "10151392618785579",
          "10151392618835579",
          "10151392618885579",
          "10151392619010579",
          "10151392619155579"
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is the code I have used to fetch the data:

```
// GET THE APP DATA
if (JOFeeds.has("app_data"))    {
    String strAppData = JOFeeds.getString("app_data");

    if (strAppData.equals("[]"))    {
        // DO NOTHING
    } else {

        JSONObject JOAppData = new JSONObject(strAppData);

        if (JOAppData.has("photo_ids")) {
            String strPhotoIDS = JOAppData.getString("photo_ids");

            JSONArray JAPhotoIDS = new JSONArray(strPhotoIDS);
            Log.e("JAPhotoIDS", JAPhotoIDS.toString());

            for (int j = 0; j < JAPhotoIDS.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject JOPhotoIDS = JAPhotoIDS.getJSONObject(j);
                Log.e("PHOTO IDS", JOPhotoIDS.toString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The logcat however, always shows this error:

```
12-13 15:54:36.390: W/System.err(5841): org.json.JSONException: Value 10151392619250579 at 0 of type java.lang.Long cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Clearly I am wrong in the coding. Can anyone provide any suggestions on what the proper approach / code should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the part where you are parsing the `photo_ids` is wrong, it should be like:

```
if (JOAppData.has("photo_ids")) {
        JSONArray JAPhotoIDS = JOAppData.getJSONArray("photo_ids");
        Log.e("JAPhotoIDS", JAPhotoIDS.toString());

        for (int j = 0; j < JAPhotoIDS.length(); j++) {
            String id = JAPhotoIDS.getString(j);
            Log.e("PHOTO IDS", id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My my. I have been at it for well over 5 hours now and all you took was like a minute. You Sir, are a Wizard. :-)

Comment: There seems to be a timer before I can accept this answer. May I ask a follow up question until then?

Comment: Thank you. Basically, I am adding all collected data to an ArrayList<FQLFeedsData> where `FQLFeedsData` is a Class to define my setters and getters (for my adapter). Some results, as shown in the question have more than one ID. How do I add all ID's in one result set to an array and pass to my adapter? Or should I rather post a new question for this?

Comment: if i understand well, you can define array of strings (`String[] ids`) inside your class `FQLFeedsData`..if this is not the answer you want..make a new question explaining more what you want

Comment: Right. Let me give that a shot. But I suspect, in case of any hiccups, I would be better off posting a new question. Thanks for helping out. I appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSONArray JAPhotoIDS includes an array of `Long` (not JSONObject).
So instead using

```
JSONObject JOPhotoIDS = JAPhotoIDS.getJSONObject(j);
```

use

```
Long lPhotoIDS = JAPhotoIDS.getLong(j);
```

Comment: +1. For _almost_ nailing it. Perhaps it's my fault for not mentioning I needed to extract the data as String.